# Método para inserir no banco não está puxando valor [JAVA]

Tags: java, mysql, sql, netbeans, crud

Boa noite!

Estou tentando fazer um trabalho da faculdade (JAVA), e tenho que inserir os dados de cliente no banco de dados (MySQL), tenho uma classe de Cliente, um formulário, e a classe do banco.

Formulário chamando o método para inserção (alterei algumas para não ficar poluído)

```
private void btIncluirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
cliente.setNome(txtNome.getText());

    try {
        vServCadCliente.insertNome();
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Inserido com sucesso");
        limpaTela();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(frmCadCliente.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
}
```

Classe de do banco (método de inserção)

```
public void insertNome()throws SQLException{

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Achou");

        String sql = "insert into NOME(NOME)" +
        "values (?)";
        PreparedStatement ps;
        ps = conexao.getConexao().prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, cliente.getNome());
        //usar sempre pra inserir ou modificar dado na tabela
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Achou 2");
        ps.executeUpdate();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Achou 2");
        ps.close();
        conexao.close();
    }
```

Realizamos o debug, e o formulário está setando o valor da variável, mas quando vamos para o método da classe do banco, ele busca o ps.setString(1, cliente.getNome()) como NULL, não está puxando da classe de clientes.

Comment: o método `insertNome()` não deveria receber o cliente como parâmetro?

Comment: No caso, eu deveria colocar o objeto cliente como parâmetro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que você muito provavelmente está pegando o objeto de cliente errado e além disso há também outras coisas para se melhorar na arquitetura do seu projeto então vamos lá.

Primeiro este cara aqui "vServCadCliente", resumidamente este cara me da a entender que você criou uma classe pra cada funcionalidade do seu crud (Cadastro, atualização, pesquisa...) para melhorar isto você poderia criar uma classe responsável somente para administrar essas funcionalidades para o objeto de Cliente, algo como:

ClienteDAO que será composto pelos métodos

- public boolean inserirCliente(Cliente cliente)
- public boolean atualizarCliente(Cliente cliente)
- public boolean removerCliente(int codCliente)
- public ArrayList buscarClientes()

Obs: Ao invés de criar um método para atualizar e outro para inserir você pode criar um método que já faça ambas as coisas, tipo:

```
int upsertCliente(Cliente cliente) {
  //Se o cliente não tem código é porque ele não foi cadastro no banco 
  if(cliente.getCdCliente() == null) {
    //código para cadastrar
  } else {
    //código para atualizar
  }
}
```

Obs2: Nos métodos de inserção, remoção e atualização é interessante você colocar algo que diga se o método conseguiu ou não realizar o seu papel, por isso coloquei um boolean como retorno(true se não ocorreu erro durante a operação ou false se tiver ocorrido), pois assim você poderá mostrar ao usuário mensagens do tipo "Cliente cadastrado com Sucesso", "Ocorreu um erro inesperado", etc... No caso do upsert o retorno é um int, pois dessa forma você poderá retornar 0 para erros, 1 para cadastro bem sucedido, e 2 para para atualizações bem sucedidas, o ideal seria criar algo como um enum para isso mas já me alonguei demais nesta observação.

Agora com o ClienteDAO feito basta você criar um objeto dele e chamar o método que você irá utilizar, ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
 private ClienteDAO clienteDAO;

 //Construtor da sua Tela
 FormularioCliente() {
   clienteDAO = new ClienteDAO();
 }

 private void btnSalvarCliente(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

   Cliente novoCliente = new Cliente();
   novoCliente.setNome(txtNome.getText());
   novoCliente.setCpf(txtCpf.getText());        
   novoCliente.setTelefone(txtTelefone.getText());
   novoCliente.setEmail(txtEmail.getText());

  if(clienteDAO.inserirCliente(novoCliente)) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cliente cadastrado com sucesso");
    limpaTela();
  } else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ocorreu um erro inesperado, não for possível cadastrar o cliente");
  }

}
```

Sua classe ClienteDAO

```
public boolean inserirCliente(Cliente cliente){
    String sql = "INSERT INTO cliente(nome,cpf,email,telefone) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
    try { 
    PreparedStatement ps = conexao.getConexao().prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, cliente.getNome());
        ps.setString(2, cliente.getCpf());
        ps.setString(3, cliente.getEmail());
        ps.setString(4, cliente.getTelefone());
        ps.execute();
        ps.close();
        //Consegui inserir
        return true;
    } 
    catch (SQLException u) { 
        //Não consegui inserir
        throw new RuntimeException(u);
        return false;
    } 

}
```

Última Obs: Eu não testei nada do código e também não sei como estão as outras coisas no seu projeto, mas o importante aqui é a ideia, que em resumo é a de criar uma classe ClienteDAO que irá organizar e descrever **TODAS** as interações que a sua classe de Cliente realizará com o banco de dados.